# How to set breakpoints in de-compiled classes from jar for remote debugging in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a remote server that is running a Java program in debug mode.

It has the following Java opts:
    JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"

I can successfully connect to it with an IntelliJ Debugger.

I can stop the process from IntelliJ and also get thread dumps.

I would now like to add a breakpoint for a certain method. However, using the Breakpoint window to set i.e. a wildcard match for class pattern and a method name works theoretically, but it is so extremely slow that it’s impossible to use it to debug web requests.

I do have the jar available so I would like IntelliJ to decompile the jar, show it to me as source code and allow me to set breakpoints in the decompiled jar.

How can I achieve this?

(I have full permissions to do this and also the actual source code available, but for legal reasons I cannot transfer the source code to the machine from where I‘m debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be fairly simple:

1. Open the folder with all the jars in IntelliJ (they show as a list but aren’t „browsable“
2. Right-click the folder, „Open Module Settings“
3. Go to „Libraries“
4. Click „+“ and then „Java“
5. Select all the jars in that directory
6. Now all the jars are browsable
7. Set breakpoints in the jar code